# Do java Vertx event-loops share the same thread? Or is it one to one?

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-verticle

This is regarding the java Vertx event loops. Is one thread attached to one event loop ?  or can a single thread run multiple event loops?

Comment: [This post](https://alexey-soshin.medium.com/understanding-vert-x-event-loop-46373115fb3e) could be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the event loop in itself is a separate thread (which should not be blocked). But there can be more than one event loops.

From the documentation [here](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_reactor_and_multi_reactor) and [here](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_verticles)

> Instead of a single event loop, each Vertx instance maintains several event loops. By default, we choose the number based on the number of available cores on the machine, but this can be overridden.

> A Vert.x instance maintains N event loop threads (where N by default is core*2) by default.

Comment: This I understood, but my question whether a single thread runs multiple event loops?

Comment: A single thread runs a single event loop @dGayand

Comment: Do you have any thing that I can refer to which says this ?

Comment: By inference, 
- all over the Vertx documentation it says the _event loop thread_, 
-In cases when there are many event loops ([here](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_verticles) for example), it says loop threads (with s meaning separate thread for each event loop.
> `A Vert.x instance maintains N event loop threads`
- Also, emphasis is always on no blocking the event loop thread. If there were a single thread running multiple event loops, emphasis will be on not blocking the single thread running the event loops because it will in turn block all event loops.

Answer (score 0):

Tcheutchoua Steve is correct in the answer.

> For event loop tasks, size of the thread pool is two times the CPU count by default

You can see it yourself using that example:

```
class MyVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    private final Map<String, AtomicInteger> threadCounts;

    MyVerticle(Map<String, AtomicInteger> threadCounts) {
        this.threadCounts = threadCounts;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        threadCounts.computeIfAbsent(Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                t -> new AtomicInteger(0)).incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

If you'd like to understand Vert.x Event Loop more, you can read my article on the subject:

https://alexey-soshin.medium.com/understanding-vert-x-event-loop-46373115fb3e